# how to get string resource from string.xml file in android

Tags: java, android, xml

I am using the following code. Although the code is working fine. I want to get string from `string.xml` file without initialising strings in Java code?  I have no clue on what to do. Also I want to make the following: On particular list item click it starts a new activity?

```
package com.example.listviewexample;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends ListActivity {

    final List<String> elements = Arrays.asList("Element 1", "Element 2", "Element 3",
            "Element 4", "Element 5");

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        //setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        ListView listView = getListView();
        listView.setTextFilterEnabled(true);    
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                R.layout.activity_main,elements);
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);
        listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                    int position, long id) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        ((TextView) view).getText(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }``
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: context.getResources().getStringArray(R.id.myarray)

Comment: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/string-resource.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

define the Array into your `arrays.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>  
    <resources>  
     <array name="myArray">  
    <item>Element 1</item>  
    <item>Element 2</item>  
    <item>Element 3</item>  
    <item>Element 4</item>  
    <item>Element 5</item>  
     </array>
</resources>
```

Load the elements:

```
String[] elements = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.myArray);  
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.activity_main,elements);
```

Comment: where to define the array? in the string.xml file only or somewhere else. Thanks for help

Comment: into the values/arrays.xml

Answer (score 0):

As Jorgesys says you should declare it in your `values/arrays.xml`

If you need different translations for this strings, you should create this `arrays.xml` in his respective `values` folder.

See [Android Localization link](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/localization.html) for more help about this.